# How to return object in Array.from second argument in Javscript

Tags: javascript

`Array.from` works when returning `true`

```js
console.log((Array.from(Array(3), (_) => true)))
```

In reality:

```
[ true, true, true ]
```

However, if I want to create a object array, how can I do?

```js
console.log((Array.from(Array(3), (_) => {"a": "b"})))
```

Excpect:

```
[{"a": "b"}, {"a": "b"}, {"a": "b"}]
```

In reality:

```
';' expected.ts(1005)
```